# linq-to-xml and carriage returns

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

What is the best what to handle carriage returns in xml formatting with xml?

```
<myxml>
<mydata>
</mydata>
</myxml>

<myxml><mydata></mydata></myxml>
```

Comment: Why does this have the linq-to-xml tag on it?

Comment: Are you trying to output XML, read XML, or what? If you're reading linq-to-XML won't have problems with carriage returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference.

If you want the XML to be smaller, don't add newlines.
If you want it to be human-readable, add newlines and indentation.

LINQ to XML will format the XML with tabs and newlines by default; to prevent this, call `element.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)`